# What to do when NIKKOR 55-200mm lens behaves like it is not attached to the camera, even though it is attached?

Tags: lens, nikon, troubleshooting, focus

I just purchased a Nikon D5500 with the 18-55mm and 55-200mm lenses, along with one digital high-def 2.2x teleconverter and a digital high-def .43x super wide angle lens with macro filter.

The 18-55mm lens works just fine with and without the teleconverter.

However, with my 55-200mm lens, it was working fine, focusing well and taking normal pictures, and then I attached the .43x filter.  The edges of the picture were a bit blurry.  Then, I carefully removed the .43x filter (keeping the 55-200mm lens on), and through the viewfinder, it looked as if there was no lens attached!

I have tried CAREFULLY brushing dust off the lens with a dust blower, I have attached and reattached the lens, I have checked the settings (IMPORTANT: even though I have read the user manual thoroughly, I still do not understand some terminology/might have overlooked some of the settings).  I would say I am between a beginner/intermediate photographer.  Is there anything I can do about my situation?

Comment: If you put the 18-55 back on, that works fine?

Comment: What do you mean it looks as if no lens is attached?  Everything blurry and/or dark?  Or just a little out of focus?

Comment: Yes, the camera works fine with the 18-55 back on. However, even with the 55-200mm on, the view through the viewfinder on the camera is the same (blurry, kind of dark unless pointed at a light), however, I have now realized that I can look at some things extremely close up 55-200, it just will take a grainy and dark photo.

Comment: Try to attach the lens directly to the camera without the teleconverter.

Answer (score 1):

I called Nikon to troubleshoot the same macro lens you have.  It was determined that it was probably defective.  I am sending it back to get it fixed or potentially get a new one.  I can only deduct that the same situation might be happening to you, as my lens was behaving the same way.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it looks like there is no lens attached, the only thing that comes to mind is the battery being flat.  Given it's a new camera, try charging up the battery.  With a dead battery you see almost nothing through the viewfinder. Very dark and very blurry (not just out of focus).  With the battery charged it might look blurry if the lens wasn't focusing, but it wouldn't look like no lens attached.

Suggest charging the battery first.

Try the 18-55mm to isolate whether it's the 55-200mm lens or the camera body

Put the lens/body on manual focus and see if changing focus makes the picture reasonably sharp - it should if the batter is charged

Comment: Hi, I tried charging the battery all night, and the lens is still the same!  The 18-55mm lens works great-- by itself and with the 2.2x teleconverter.  However, being new to the camera (and a beginner when it comes to using DSLR cameras)-- how to you put it in manual (this is probably a very stupid question)?  I read the whole instruction manual and I am still a bit confused by this camera!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to get it into manual. Lens still does not work.